# Launch coroutine before create the activity Android

Tags: android, android-activity, android-lifecycle, coroutine

I need to do a job before rendering the activity

> setContentView

is this example is right, if not what is the best way to lunch coroutine in this case

```
 override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?, persistentState: PersistableBundle?) {
    lifecycleScope.launchWhenCreated {
        if (dataStoreRepository.getLanguage() == ARABIC)
            window.decorView.layoutDirection = View.LAYOUT_DIRECTION_RTL
        else
            window.decorView.layoutDirection = View.LAYOUT_DIRECTION_LTR
    }
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState, persistentState)
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is not the best place to perform this action, since you need to block the main thread and it'll probably cause some dropped frames (especially on slower devices).

Better places to do it:

- In the application class, before any activities are created (store the layout direction somewhere that can be easily access... shared preferences etc).
- In the activity immediately proceeding this one (if there was one).

In both cases, you would ideally show a progress indicator and lock the UI to avoid any dropped frames.

Comment: I didn't know how to access the application from my BaseActivity do you have any ideas on how to access that info

Comment: Sure, you wouldn't typically access it from your activity, you would create a new class that extends `Application` and list it in your manifest file.
A tutorial that explains it can be found here:
https://medium.com/droid-log/android-application-class-a8a1d64c82d1

Comment: Thank you very much man, You are the best, I accepted your answer, and Now I marked as useful. All thanks :)

Comment: No problem, glad to help!

Comment: But there is the case, I applied the article example, but the window object is only allowed in the activity, I tried this solution but my problem is not in the application, I need to use this in an activity, How to solve this now ?

Comment: That's correct, typically you would just set a property in the application class (`isArabic` for example) and then the activities would access the `Application` class and set `window.decorView.layoutDirection` based on this value.

Is this the first activity used in the application?

Comment: Actually, I need tp access this property (IsArabic) in each activity, So I think If I can implement this in the BaseActivity, But I have no idea how to implement this :(